# Why would WIN10 throttle my apps but not speedtest or speedguide? (if not VerizonFIOS)

Tags: internet, throttling, win10-fast-startup

Win10, VerizonFios 25/25 Mbps shows about that speed on speedtest.net and speedguide.net
But firefox accessing gmail or other websites, or other apps I use, show mostly 0.1Mbps (1/2 second on 1/2 second off) and occasionally 1-2 Mbps (not MBPS) on task manager Network column.
However task manager Network column shows 17 - 22 Mbps when running speedtest thru firefox - this is next to the firefox process name.

So I am thinking firefox can download at rated speeds when running speedtest but not when accessing othersites and my apps are also throttled.
This was not the case 5 or 6 months ago before Verizon sent me 5 or 6 emails to upgrade to their 50/50 service which I declined everytime.
I talked to VerizonFIOS support multiple times and their answer was network is fine and pointed me to speedtest results. One time after running tests on fast.com which showed 600kbps down load speed I mentioned it to them. They still said they could find no problems with my connection - however the next day when I tested again on Fast.com to copy results to show them it then showed 20 Mbps - can they selectively un-throttle a website? Is fast.com now compromised as a test site (or only for me)?

Is it Verizon throttling my access or is Win10 somehow involved in throttling applications (query due to the 1/2 second pulsing of the network traffic from 0.1 Mbps to 0.0 Mbps and back) If so why is WIN10 allowing speedtest related access unhindered while throttling other processes like firefox accessing gmail or my other apps?

unfortunately have another 10 months of the 2 Yr contract with Verizon but will have to opt for month to month with other carrier (only one) available to me. What a state for broadband access.

TIA

Comment: The internet doesn't work the way it seems you think it does. Speed is determined by the source server, not the internet speed you've paid for. Gmail doesn't sent all that much information and so doesn't have to dedicate much bandwidth to a given client connection. Speedtest servers dedicate more bandwidth in order to test. Now, if you focused not on checking the task manager's throughput ratings and instead compared the relative speed of loading the same site on different computers on different connections, we may have something to discuss. But right now, I don't see anything actually wrong.

Comment: Try fast.com for a speed test.  It's hosted by Netflix, so it will give a truer result.

Comment: @music2myear In that case, he could try downloading a file from Google Drive.

Comment: @essjae - thanks, I tried that and got 600 kbps (much slower than the 20+ Mbps I get on speed tests but after mentioning to Verizon FIOS support next day the speed on fast.com was good above 20 Mbps but not for anything else.

Comment: @music2myear - I get what you are saying and can understan that at times the servers can additionally get overloaded - but two things make  me question that - 1. all apps and firefox access to gmail and websites were much faster (and had markedly improved when Verizon sold me upgrade from 15/15 Mbps to 25/25 Mbps and, 2. gmail takes 30 to 40 seconds to load - in keeping with 0.1 Mbps which is 100kbps near DSL, Apps which used to load in a few seconds now take minutes  -- can't imagine everyone's servers really got overloaded in 4-5 months ago. Or may be I clobbered my OS installation (/)

Comment: @RogUE - thanks - opened my Google Drive page (after a long time) - it took about a minute and 10 seconds to load - not sure if that is normal - Task manager Network column showed similar behaviour - a few readings of 3 Mbps but mostly 0.3 or 0.1 Mbps cycling on and off at about 1/2 second rate.

Comment: ISPs are notorious for faking the results of speedtests, the number of websites that are used for that purpose, are easily added to a white list.  Additionally, if Google websites are the only websites with a speed issue, then it's a ISP problem.

Comment: @Ramhound - absolutely agree with the sentiment that ISPs can be crooked - I expect that it's not souch faking the results as "optimising the network" for better results to test sites - so the results are real but highly misleading. I also agree the Google are very focused on good connectivity.

Comment: If you have a Linux system, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253872/measuring-and-documenting-internet-speed-download-and-upload) might be useful for you.